# Using mongoid-multitenancy, how to turn scope off during a given query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, multi-tenant

I'm using [mongoid-multitenancy](https://github.com/PerfectMemory/mongoid-multitenancy) to achieve multi-tenancy, but I would like to turn it off during a query.

> ```
> @article = Article.find(params[:id])
> ```

I want everybody to read articles but not edit all of them. Is there a way to make query unscoped with mongoid-multitenancy?

Comment: You can use Mongoid::Multitenancy.with_tenant(nil) { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's easy than imagined, you just need to access the unscoped scope.

```
@article = Article.unscoped.find(params[:id])
```